# Can't retain double quotation in url using php

Tags: php

i want to make url after registration like this:?goal="regSuccess" but after registration we have ?goal=-regSuccess-.how can i fix it?
thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want or need quotes round a parameter?

Comment: ... we need a bit more information than that. If it's a specific rule you have, let us know. You can't expect us to answer your question when you don't give us the information. Try `urlencode()` like @m02ph3u5 suggested if you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php). You should always url-encode the parameter values unless you are sure that they don't need to be url-encoded.

/edit: If you can't figure out why it transforms double quotes to "-" then try to base64-encode the param as soon in the code as possible (or the whole query string) and decode again wherever you need it. This might fix the symptom for you (not the actual issue, though).